# can't deploy from VS2010 to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, deployment

I have run VS 2010 as an administrator
The user, which is running VS2010, have db_owner rights to the config, content, and central admin DBs of SP2010.

In my hostfile i have

127.0.0.1   intranet.lesson.net/sites/chapter2/
::1             Intranet.lesson.net/sites/chapter2/

But still get this error
VS Error 2010
Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://intranet.lesson.net/sites/chapter2/SitePages/Home.aspx/. Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project.

Logfile
07/29/2012 14:11:15.52  vssphost4.exe (0x102C)  0x13A0  SharePoint Foundation   General 8kh7    High    0x80070002There is no Web named "/sites/chapter2/SitePages/Home.aspx".

Can anybody help me?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've specified `http://intranet.lesson.net/sites/chapter2/SitePages/Home.aspx/` as the Site URL in visual studio it should only be `http://intranet.lesson.net/sites/chapter2`.

To change this select your SharePoint project in "Solution Explorer" and it'll be in the Properties Window (F4)

Comment: Thank you Per
Yes it was the ansver
Once again you solved my problem